# Limiting distribution with two additive terms converging in distribution

Tags: distributions, convergence

I have a question related to the asymptotic distribution of an estimator $\hat{\beta}$ that tries to estimate the true parameter vector $\beta$ and can be written as

$\sqrt{N}(\hat{\beta}-\beta)=\sqrt{N}\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{\frac{1}{N}B}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\mathbf{C}$

where $\sqrt{N}\mathbf{A}$ is a random matrix that converges in distribution against a Normal with expectation $\mathbf{0}$ and variance $\mathbb{V}[\mathbf{A}]$:

$\sqrt{N}\mathbf{A} \xrightarrow{d}N(\mathbf{0},\mathbb{V}[\mathbf{A}]) $

The expression $\mathbf{\frac{1}{N}B}^{-1}$ is also a random matrix and converges by the law of large numbers and the continuous mapping theorem in probability against $(\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{B}])^{-1}$:

$\mathbf{\frac{1}{N}B}^{-1} \xrightarrow{P}$$(\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{B}])^{-1}$

For the random matrix$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\mathbf{C}$ again the law of large numbers apply such that (by using Slutsky's Theorem)  $\mathbf{\frac{1}{N}B}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\mathbf{C}$ converges in distribution against a normal with expectation $\mathbf{0}$ and variance $\mathbf{\mathbb{E}[B]^{-1}}\mathbb{V}[\mathbf{C}](\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{B^{T}])^{-1}}$ where the subscript $T$ denotes the transpose:

$\mathbf{\frac{1}{N}B}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\mathbf{C} \xrightarrow{d}N(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\mathbb{E}[B]^{-1}}\mathbb{V}[\mathbf{C}](\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{B^{T}])^{-1}})$

Note that the random variables $\mathbf{A,B,C}$ are not independent.

Now my question is whether there is some way of learning about the term $\sqrt{N}(\hat{\beta}-\beta)$ is converging against. I know from probability theory that the sum of two random variables that converge in distribution must not be the same as the sum of the two limiting variables. (i.e. $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d}X$, $Y_{n}\xrightarrow{d}Y$ does **not** imply $X_{n}+Y_{n}\xrightarrow{d}X+Y$)

Is there any way out of this problem? Or can I impose more strict assumptions in order to learn about the limiting distribution?